# Using Invoke Method in an IF statement vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, if-statement, label, invoke

I am using a TCP client/server to receive information from a micro controller and using that information inside a Win Forms App, VB.NET. My issue is trying to check a label against a datatable in an IF statement. I have tried different forms of invoke but none of them seem to work.
VB Code

```
If lblStep.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub() lblStep.Text = lblStep.Text), Nothing) = dt.Rows(0).Item("Step") Then
'Do something
end if
```

The error I am receiving is a multi thread error.

Comment: Use the Form as marshaller and check whether the handle of the Control you need is created before you try to read its properties. What is this supposed to set: `lblStep.Text = lblStep.Text`? Note that the `If` condition needs to be tested inside the method, not outside.

Comment: Are you trying to evaluate whether the text of a Control contains *something* and, based on the result of the test, set the value of a Cell? Of test whether the text of a Control is the same as the content of a Cell, then do *something else*? -- Set `Option Strict On` if you haven't already.

Comment: @Jimi I am trying to evaluate if the text of the label is equal to the value of the datatable cell.  The handle of the control is created before the reading of its properties.

Comment: That code is nonsensical. The only thing you're doing on the UI thread is assigning the `Text` of a `Label` to itself. You seem to be expecting `Invoke` to return a value that you can then compare to something but how is `Invoke` supposed to return anything if it invokes a `Sub`? If you expect a return value then you have to invoke a method that returns a value, i.e. a `Function`. Of course, what's the point of invoking a method to get a return value and then comparing when you can just compare in that method?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect to get a value returned then you need to invoke a method that returns a value, which means a function. You could do this:

```vb
If CStr(lblStep.Invoke(Function() lblStep.Text)) = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("Step") Then
```

or this:

```vb
If CBool(lblStep.Invoke(Function() lblStep.Text = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("Step"))) Then
```

The first one gets the `String` from the UI thread and performs the comparison on the background thread while the second performs the comparison on the UI thread.

Note that I also make sure that everything is the correct data type, which is required if you have set `Option Strict On`, which you absolutely should have done.